# push element in a array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects with objects and children and children can have elements

```
let array = {
  account: "account 1",
  children: [
    {
      account: "1",
    },
   {
      account: "2",
    },
  ],
  total: {
    debit: 96,
    credit:96,
  },
},
  {
    account: "account 2",
    children: [
      {
        account: "1",
      },
    ],
    total: {
      debit: 45,
      credit: 96,
    },
  }
]
```

The expected array is to push an object to each of the children here and the object will be the total object we have at the bottom.

Expected Result:

```
let resultArray = {
  account: "account 1",
  children: [
    {
      account: "1",
    },
   {
      account: "2",
    },
   {
    debit: 96,
    credit:96,
  },
  ],
  total: {
    debit: 96,
    credit:96,
  },
},
  {
    account: "account 2",
    children: [
      {
        account: "1",
      },
    {
      debit: 45,
      credit: 96,
    },
    ],
    total: {
      debit: 45,
      credit: 96,
    },
  },
```

Any suggestions for the same?

Comment: Please read [tour]: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: Please fix your code above in order to show what you want. `array` and `resultArray` are neither valid arrays not objects.

Comment: Right now is hard to understand your question since those arrays are not valid. Please fix it and clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resultArray = array.map((data) => {
   const newChildrenArray = [...data.children];
   newChildrenArray.push({...data.total});
   return { ...data, children: newChildrenArray };
});
```

Note:
Your array and resultArray are not valid.
They should be like:
let array = [obj1, obj2]

Hope this will solve your problem!